# Unable to set start page (to windows form) in MFC application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

At a broader level, I'm converting a `MFC application (MFC 6.0)` into `Windows Forms application (Visual Studio 2013)`. I read certain blogs that describes that this conversion is possible. By this conversion I can re-use code written in MFC, only I will need to create UI. However I will need to understand the previous code and may need to re-write it a bit.

I got the motivation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836511/what-are-some-techniques-for-migrating-a-large-mfc-application-to-wpf-net) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MFCToDotNet12212006121020PM/MFCToDotNet.aspx).

I have performed following steps so far.

> 1. Opened Visual C++ 6.0 project in Visual Studio 2013.
> 2. Build it successfully.
> 3. Then added CLR support to it, and fixed errors.
> 4. Added a Windows form, and added controls to it. [As mentioned here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MFCToDotNet12212006121020PM/MFCToDotNet.aspx).
> 5. Added functionality and build it successfully.
> 6. Now when I run this application, then it still point to old MFC window.

I'm missing certain settings which will change the rendering window from MFC to WindowsForm. What am I missing here?

Addition to that, I see problem with this approach as described by @Roger in comments, and I understand that. So, I wanted to know for any tool/utility which may convert legacy code into C#. Does such utility available?

TIA.

Comment: You know, it's not some magic setting, that miraculously makes your window appear on screen. It's code. Readable. Debuggable. Apply both, not necessarily in that order.

Comment: It sounds to me like it would be much easier to create a Windows Forms application, add the controls to it, then port the logic. Trying to get a quick win always ends up with a slow painful loss.

Comment: @RogerRowland that is another way to do it... I have a very huge project where I want to do this.. So instead of creating a new WinApp, I just want to do modifications in current MFC app. I have successfully created first screen, only the matter is, I'm not able to link it with CWinApp object..

Comment: *"huge project"* .... *"I have successfully..."* ..... *"I'm not able to ..."* .... yep, this is only the first of your many problems ;-) I strongly suggest you try the way I mentioned, it will also give you an opportunity to refactor and take advantage of the .NET Framework where appropriate too.

Comment: @RogerRowland I don't mind to go in that approach too..Then clear my one doubt.. the code that was written in old MFC application was written using Visual C++ (all windows control/handlers etc), and when I start working with WindowsForm then it uses C#. So how these two different languages will work together.. or how can I port every bit of C++ code in C#?

Comment: @RogerRowland two more things.. First, do you know a way to set the start page in my current appraoch? Second, if I go with your approach then what code I can port to WindowsForm and how? Because my concern is different languages. I can compile one DLL of existing code, but how that C++ code will help, I'm figuring out that yet.

Comment: C# and C++ are quite similar. However, the point I'm trying to make is that you are porting *functionality*, not porting *code*. You need to read and understand what the MFC application does, then reimplement that same functionality using C# and WinForms. There's no quick win.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87779/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-roger-rowland).

Comment: C++/CLI is the tool to port functionality **and** code. Since you don't know MFC, nor C#, nor C++, nor the tools involved, this isn't going to be easy. Or even possible.

Comment: @IInspectable I know flow of MFC application, I have worked on that.. I have worked on C#.. And c++ I did in school days.. However it would have been good to give some real help instead taunting whatever who u r.. If u hv knowledge then share it else stay away.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you are referring to seems suitable for amending a MFC application with a few forms as child windows to make use of .NET features. However, the main window is another story. You wrote the application is huge, so I suppose you don't want a simple form as your main window and rather have some kind of MDI interface in mind. If you replace the `CMainFrame` in the legacy MFC application, it just doesn't make sense to maintain an old `CWinApp` class. Anyway, if you are hell-bent on going down that path, you may want to have a look at an [old CodeProject articel (.NET1.x, .NET2.x)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12563/Hosting-of-MFC-MDI-Applications-from-Within-WinFor) to get a better grasp at the whole concept.

But as Roger already suggested, it would be a wise choice to find a nice GUI framework, perhaps even WPF instead of WindowsForms, and do a GUI rewrite -- especially if one part of the motivation for the conversion is to move to newer UI concepts. If your C++ program logic is well separated in your MFC project, put it in a COM server and make use of [interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx).

Comment: C++/CLI is **a lot** better suited to implement an interop layer, than creating a COM server. Unless your application is already implemented using COM, go with C++/CLI (see [.NET Programming with C++/CLI (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx)).