# How to import WPF GUI forms into MFC application

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc

I have simple MFC legacy application. 
I need to create some 5 new screens with very nice GUI - so i decide to do it with WPF. 
I'm using VS 2010

My questions are

1. I don't see any possible to create WPF library in creating new project menu.
2. How can i import the WPF Dll that i will create into the MFC ?
3. How can i create an instance of the WPF form MFC and make the Form 'DoModol()' call ?

Comment: See [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/nfc/article.php/c14589/Hosting-WPF-Content-in-an-MFC-Application.htm) article

Comment: Start from this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829952/how-do-i-host-wpf-content-in-mfc-applications