# WPF Control inside LISTCONTROL of MFC

Tags: c++, wpf, winapi, mfc, custom-controls

I am working on the windows form based application using `MFC` in visual studio 2010. Running on `clr` I have attached `WPFuserlibrary` with it to use WPF contrl in the project. I want to make the `Custom List Control` so I can display the `WPF` control for e.g. a button in every row of list.

```
hwndWPF1 = GetHwnd(m_democontrol.GetSafeHwnd(),20,20, 20,20);
```

this is how i am displaying the `HWND` object But this draws on the form or list view. I want to draw this inside `listcontrol` in every row. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have done all these steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829952/how-do-i-host-wpf-content-in-mfc-applications

Comment: This part is of displaying WPF control in MFC dialog and I have down this part . I am talking of one step furter where I can place this control in ListControl or gridControl correspoding to each row in the list control.