# How do I place a managed WPF program inside an unmanaged MFC window

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I got already 2 complete functioning and with one another communicating programs, one written in MFC/C++ and one made with WPF/C#.

The communication works as follows:
On selection of an item inside the the unmanaged MFC/C++ program a window opens with the WPF/C# Program. Data is being transmitted as well, on selection of the specific item the Window with the data needed for it opens.

To the problem:
The WPF window should be shown inside the MFC window. No new window should be opened.

Is it possible to host the managed program inside the unmanaged MFC one?

I only need to change the placement of the application to be shown in a MFC window.

Comment: you can if you have a managed MFC app- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829952/how-do-i-host-wpf-content-in-mfc-applications. Otherwise no.

Comment: @auburg as I understand this, I would have to rewrite the wpf/application with c++ code to do this, which is not what need.