# Basic example of WPF hosting in c++/MFC

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I am trying to Host a WPF application inside a C++/MFC window.

I found this answer, but because of my lack in C++ knowledge I fail in following it:
[How do I host WPF content in MFC Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829952/how-do-i-host-wpf-content-in-mfc-applications)

I don't have the reputation to comment there so I am asking here if someone has a very (very) basic example of this.

I need to make a basic wpf window with a button that generically adds TextBlocks to a stackpanel

```
namespace wpfExample
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      TextBlock tBlock = new TextBlock();
      tBlock.Text = "Example";
      StPanel.Children.Add(tBlock);
   }
}
```

where StPanel is the Name of the StackPanel

Now on the C++ side I need a CPropertyPage(CDialog or CWnd) Type, with the WPF Page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/589U6.png
This is from an example I found which shows how it should look like(only in the right top corner should be the wpf window)
The Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms771352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx